# How to show related objects in Django/Admin?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'thing/icon/')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'thing/image/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Thing(models.Model):
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'thing/icon/')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'thing/image/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am using Django's admin site for basic CRUD operations. I need to show all Things in Category if I am selecting an Category in admin.

Answer (score 50):

You can use "Inlines" to visualize and edit Things of a certain Category in the admin detail for that category:

In the admin.py file, create an Inline object for Thing (ThingInline) and modify your CategoryAdmin class to have an inline of type ThingInline like this:

```
...
class ThingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Thing

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ThingInline,
    ]
...
```

For further details, this is the docs for admin inlines: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: Inlines do not show current existing objects. It show form to add them.

Comment: Did you try it? Unless I'm missing something I just double checked a live project of mine that uses Inlines and it does show current existing objects. In my case I have a couple of them, in your case it could be a lot but I think you can play with `max_num`

Comment: I think MatteoScotuzzi's answer is correct. @KenanBek if you didn't see them then there may exist some other problems in your code.

Comment: Ok I will check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. Down bellow I had added an answer that sums with @Matteo Scotuzzi's.

Answer (score 10):

update `admin.py` file like this.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import Category, Thing

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ThingInline,
    ]

class ThingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Thing

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin) 
admin.site.register(Thing)
```

There are two inline options `TabularInline` and `StackedInline`

Answer (score 4):

Few minutes ago, searching how to solve a similar problem, I finally found a solution.

You actually have to follow @Matteo Scotuzzi answer as well, then

Inside admin.py located in the app your created those models, you have to declare as follows right bellow @Matteo snippet:

```
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

and that would be enough to make all "Things" appear in "Category" inside your Django Administration respective page which is "Category".

Comment: Thanks, pretty helpful

Comment: I bet it should be `admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)`

Comment: @woodz for the day I made that answer it was tested and was working for the 2.0 / 2.2 version of the django.

Comment: @R.R.C. are you absolutely sure about that? I'm using Django 2.2 and this is what `admin.register.site()` throws: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'site'`. You need to access the `site` property of the `admin` first, then call `register`.

Comment: @Luca Bezerra, it has some time I haven't taken a look to that code again, and I can't remember it now, but to avoid future confusions I edited that line in my answer to be what it must be.