# how to represent class instances in another class

Tags: django

I am new to django and I want to represent instances of class Item in class Category ( so when I go to pizza category I want to see margarita pizza and any other created item )

so here is my admin interface

[image: admin interface]

and this is the pizza categorie

[image: created category pizza]

Item margarita pizza in Items table

[image]

and this is my models.py code

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.db import models


class Customer (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=1000 , unique=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=3000)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100 , unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order (models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total = models.IntegerField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='orders')


class Item (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100 ,unique=True)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    item_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='res/images')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category , related_name='items' , on_delete=    models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item.name

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ItemInline,
    ]
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Item , Order , Customer

admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Order)
admin.site.register(Item)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show related objects in Django/Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657225/how-to-show-related-objects-in-django-admin)

Comment: OK I didn't understand this solution so could write the code to be implemented in my case ? and explain the syntax , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create an inline admin class for your item:

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
```

Then, you can include it in your `CategoryAdmin` class:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ItemInline,
    ]
```

and register your admin class like this:

```
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

instead of just:

```
admin.site.register(Category)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @AliZain restart your server

Comment: I did restart it

Comment: @AliZain can you post your admin classes as well?

Comment: I edited the post , edited models.py 
and shared admin.py

Comment: @AliZain see the updated answer. There is an issue in your code where you register an admin class.

Comment: @AliZain glad I could help. Could you please accept the answer then?