# ForeignKey Reciprocation

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, django-admin

I want to be able to see the existance of the ForeignKey, but in the other admin.py app. The one to which is the receiver of the ForeignKey. In this case, I want to be able to see the Email ForeignKey in the Client admin.py.

**Client App Structure:**

> Project
>
> > Client
> >
> > > model.py

Client model.py Code:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    primary_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unique_num = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=30, default='Name Not Found')
    number = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

**Email App Structure:**

> Project
>
> > Email
> >
> > > model.py

Client model.py Code:

```
class ScheduledEmail(models.Model):
    primary_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    recipient_name = models.TextField()
    subject = models.TextField()
    message = models.TextField()
    datetime_sent = models.TextField(max_length=20, default='Not Yet Sent')
    datetime_created = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    recipient_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='Email Not Found')
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Client,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  related_name='scheduled_emails_sent')
```

Comment: Suppose that **One client is linked to many email**, you can edit your `Client` model and change `email` field to `email = models.ForeignKey(ScheduledEmail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: No. One client can have multiple emails.

Comment: Yes i updated the comment

Comment: Adding a ForeignKey isn't the proper solution I believe.

Comment: And how do you plan to display this field in the admin ? You have two choices : **Display the recipient field of the ScheduledEmail or add a foreignkey to Client and display it in the admin**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show related objects in Django/Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657225/how-to-show-related-objects-in-django-admin)

Comment: @BrianD I actually believe so! But it is across apps, so I therefore need to import. I will to to do it and get back to you.

Comment: Yes importing shouldn't be a problem